# Why didn't Harvey Specter send Mike Ross to get a law degree instead of hiring him immediately?

Tags: suits

Points to notice:

1. Harvey Specter was clearly impressed by Mike Ross' ability.
2. Mike Ross wanted to get out of criminal activity.
3. Mike Ross stated that he always wanted to be a lawyer, but he was disbarred from Harvard Law School as he was caught writing exam for someone else (Trevors suggestion so he could make extra money as he was poor) he couldn't pursue it.

Hence, he could have given an offer to Mike, that since he needed to hire someone exceptional who Mike is, that he would pay for his tuition and in return when he gets his degree Mike would have to work for him. This way Mike gets a degree and Harvey has hired an associate, for future.

We know Jessica paid for Harvey's Law education, so Harvey could have done the same.

Why didn't Harvey sent Mike to complete his education?

Comment: This is a classical case of only seeing the arguments against the choice of the writers and not the also obvious pros. I'm sure you can come up with a list of arguments against sending him to law school as well (e.g. he needs an assistance now, as most people with a degree will tell you a degree really doesn't tell much - he might not care, the tv show would be super boring ...)

Answer (score 3):

1. Mike was already blacklisted from Harvard, so he couldn't go back there and their firm only accepted Harvard graduates. So even if Mike went to some other school, it would be tough convincing Jessica to let Mike into the firm.
2. Harvey had to get an associate ASAP and didn't like any of the candidates apart from Mike so he went ahead and just hired him.
3. Law tuition costs a bomb.
4. There would be no interesting & engaging focal story if Mike ended up going to Law school and getting a degree and then joining the firm. The whole risk factor is a usp to the show